# 'https_log_t policy' of SELinux is not taken into effect

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, fedora, selinux

I was trying to set up a virtual host using apache `httpd` on a Digital Ocean Droplet running Fedora 26 Server. And I followed this tutorial: [How to Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7), assuming the similarities between Fedora and CentOS. I have followed the tutorial to set up this virtual host as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite1.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/requests_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, after the set up, I got `httpd` unable to start. It turned out that it was caused this error, as I traced to the `httpd` error log:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/error_log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So then, I looked up for solutions and found that it may due to the SELinux policies. Using `ls -lZ /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com`, the current polices is printed out as follows:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 4096 Oct  1 09:54 log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 4096 Oct  1 09:14 public_html
```

I followed [Configuring SELinux Policies for Apache Web Servers](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/) and tried to add `httpd_log_t` policy to `./log` folder, and used these:

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log(/.*)?"

$ restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com
```

However, the `log` folder still does not have `httpd_log_t` policy applied and `httpd` still cannot start, with the same error as before. 
I even tried to set the `public_html` folder with `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`, and it didn't work.

I think there may be something wrong with the setting process of policies. But I couldn't find any working solutions to this. Is there anything I missed along the process? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have just carried out the same operations as you on a F26 box and it works as expected. Check you did everything correctly.

Comment: @user430214 I copied and pasted what I typed into the Terminal to this question, and those commands didn’t work... In fact, I’ve tried all of them three times.

Comment: What is the output of `getenforce` ?

Comment: @user430214 The output is `enforcing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue was that the **two log files specified in the vhost configuration was not created, and *it seems that `httpd` does not have the power to create it somehow*.**

So I

- created an empty `error_log` and `requests_log` in `/var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/`,
- re-did the `$ semanage ...` and `$ restorecon ...` commands, to get the correct output:

.

```
Relabeled /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log from unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
Relabeled /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/error_log from unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
Relabeled /var/www/html/mywebsite1.com/log/requests_log from unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
```

And after a `httpd` restart, it all worked! The site is back to accessible, and those log files are keeping logs now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a specific type enforcement.

1. First check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for specific deny error messages. You can run this:

`sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`

2. Then run a grep against the specific error message and pipe this through audit2allow.

`grep myerror /var/log/audit/audit.log|audit2allow -v`

This will output the specific type enforcement you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In the first step with `sealert`, I got `found 0 alerts in /var/log/audit/audit.log`. And the second step yields `Nothing to do`. Does this mean it is working correctly?